# How to correctly structure the json?

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I have problems understanding json format. I have this in my CI controller:

```
public function backend($con_id, $last_id)
        {
            header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
            //header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
            header('Content-type: application/json');

            $data = $this->Msg_model->get_msg($con_id, $last_id);

            echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

Where in model:

```
public function get_msg($con_id, $last_id)
        {
            $this->db->select("msg_id, sender_id, msg");
            $this->db->where('conversation_id', $con_id);
            $this->db->where('msg_id >', $last_id);
            $this->db->order_by('msg_time', 'DESC');
            $this->db->limit(12);

            $query = $this->db->get('messages');
            return array_reverse($query->result_array());
        }
```

and in JS:

```
...
$.getJSON(baseurl + path + con_id + '/' + last_msg, function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(i,val){
            if(login_id == val.sender_id){
                $('#messagewindow' + con_id).append('<div class="bubble"><p>' + val.msg + '</p></div>');
            } else {
                $('#messagewindow' + con_id).append('<div class="bubble bubble-right"><p>' + val.msg + '</p></div>');
            }
...
```

I added "load more" button to my chat and it works fine. The problem is that I have to specify if it should be displayed. The limit for msgs loaded is 12 so I should add the button only if there is >12 messages for this conversation. I can do the checking in controller. For that I tried:

```
$data['more'] = // some stuff
            $data['msgs']= $this->Msg_model->get_msg($con_id, $last_id);

            echo json_encode($data);
```

in controller and

```
$.each(json.msgs, function(i,val){
            if(login_id == val.sender_id){
                $('#messagewindow' + con_id).append('<div class="bubble"><p>' + val.msg + '</p></div>');
            } else {
                $('#messagewindow' + con_id).append('<div class="bubble bubble-right"><p>' + val.msg + '</p></div>');
            }
        });
```

in JS but with no luck. I have been trying and reading about json for hours now... Could someone explain what do I need - json object or array...?

The question is - how to send a bunch of unrealeted data with json and then handle in JS?

For example when passing data to view you just do this in your controller:

```
$data['somedata1'] = ...
$data['somedata2']= ...
$data['somedata3'] = ...
```

and then in view:

```
<?= $somedata1?>
<?= $somedata2?>
<?= $somedata3?>
```

Comment: In your js code, wherever you are fetching the json, just do a `console.log(json)` or `console.log(json.msgs)` like you mention. You will know if it is an object or an array

Comment: for `console.log(json)` I get `Object {msgs: Array[12]}`. Expanding I get object of arrays of abjects. So the question is how to access msgs and everything thats inside it?

Comment: Cool! So `json.msgs` would be an array that you can iterate over just by doing `(json.msgs).forEach(function(item,index){ //item.<somevalidproperty>}`